# error : invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char&' from a temporary of type 'char'

Tags: c++, string, reference

> error : invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char&' from a temporary of type 'char'

I have seen the error above on a lot of posts and yet everything I try doesn't fix it.

I have the following function:

```
vector<string> splitString(const string& str, const char& ch)
{
    string next;
    vector<string> result;

    for (string::const_iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); it++)
    {
        if (*it == ch)
        {
            if (!next.empty())
            {
                result.push_back(next);
                next.clear();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            next += *it;
        }
    }

    if (!next.empty())
    {
        result.push_back(next);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Which takes a string and a character and splits the string based on the character given. I also have the following line of code to call the function:

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
     string value = "OK,OK,OK,FAULT,OK"
     vector<string> texts = splitString(value, ',');

     //Do stuff with "texts" here
}
```

**EDIT** That is my code in my main function

I have the same function, and same way of calling the function in another C++ program that I wrote which works fine, so I can't understand why it isn't working in this one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: This is not C, please don't tag it as such

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought  I had just clicked C++

Comment: Could you fashion this into an actual program starting with `int main()`? What you've pasted up here looks ok to me.

Comment: Are you sure this is the version of the code which is failing? I'd expect to see `splitString` declared with `char& ch` to get that error message.

Comment: I have added my main function and the data that is going to passed to the function. I have also checked that it is the latest version :(

Comment: [Looks fine to me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad67df55875cac8d) so long as you put a semicolon at the end of the first line in `main`.

Comment: [Seems to work...](http://ideone.com/gscPD1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best way to go about it, but I solved the error by changing my function.

For those interested, I now have:

```
vector<string> split(std::string string, std::string del)
{
    char* cstr = const_cast<char*>(string.c_str());
    char* current;
    std::vector<std::string> arr;
    current = strtok(cstr, del.c_str());
    while (current != NULL) 
    {
         arr.push_back(current);
         current = strtok(NULL, del.c_str());
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Thank you to everyone who submitted their suggestion

Comment: It is undefined behaviour to cast away `const` on the result of `c_str()` and then modify the string content via the resulting pointer.  Instead , to operate on the string content you should use `&string[0]` after checking the string is not empty.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that it is because you are passing both the string and the character as non-const references. Try changing the contents of main to:

```
 const string value = "OK,OK,OK,FAULT,OK";
 const char comma = ',';
 vector<string> texts = splitString(value, comma);
```

Comment: That results in the following error : `invalid initialization of reference of type 'char&' from expression of type 'const char'`

Comment: Hm. Does the compiler point to a specific line for this error (and your original error)?